# What happens if me and my opponent only have kings?

Tags: kings, dead-position

So, you can capture any piece in chess except for the king. But what happens if me and my opponent get all pieces captured (except for the king)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you can't move your king into check, you can't legally check the other king.

[The Laws of Chess, section 5.2b](https://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=171&view=article), states that:

> The game is drawn when a position has arisen in which neither player can checkmate the opponent’s king with any series of legal moves. The game is said to end in a ‘dead position’. This immediately ends the game, provided that the move producing the position was in accordance with Article 3 and Articles 4.2 – 4.7.

Answer (score 3):

When you only have Kings then you can take a tour of the entire board till the end of the World without any hesitation . :-) (Just Joking ) .

The Game at this point is a DRAW . Since neither Player can play without any objective and Game of Chess is all about Checkmating your King then without any material resistance it is DRAW . Infact a lone King with a Knight or Bishop and also against another King is also a DRAW material is not sufficient to Capture King .

Comment: I recall seeing two young boys playing with just their Kings, and remarking that it looked like a draw. Five minutes later I saw them putting the pieces away.

ME So you found out out it was a draw!
BOY No, he won, He got his King to the 8th rank and it became a Queen.

Maybe FIDE could consider this as a possible solution to the preponderance of draws.

Comment: @PhilipRoe - even if K promotes to Q, Q alone can't deliver mate - so quite an odd game